# How to add generic type?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have used below code in hibernate stuts2 java.

```
  String hql = "from PostDetails";
  Query postDetails = session.createQuery(hql); // Got warning from here
  List<PostDetails> result = postDetails.list();
```

Warning is : `Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<PostDetails>`

If I used this annotation @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") then warning is solved. But I don't want to any annotation.

How to fixed this warning?

Comment: I don't believe you can.  This is one of those cases in which yes, generics would be safer, but Hibernate won't return a `List` that isn't valid in that context.

Comment: The newer, standard JPA API has typed queries, that avoid those warnings. Consider using it instead of the old, proprietary, Hibernate API. Note that it isn't really type-safe though, since nothing prevents you from doing `em.createQuery("select s from School s", Student.class)` and get back a `List<Student>` that actually contains instances of School.

Comment: @JBNizet: That's almost good enough to be an answer.  Care to make it one?

Comment: @Makoto We each answered one part of the answer. Feel free to combine our comments as a unique single answer, since you were the first to correctly comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can.  Even the [documentation and examples](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-tipstricks) for Hibernate use a raw-type `List` as opposed to a typed one.  However, it is ***very unlikely*** that you will run into an error with that list; Hibernate wouldn't return a list that isn't valid in that context.

The newer, standard version of the JPA API has [typed queries](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) which would avoid those warnings, and allow you to get back a properly typed list.

That would mean you could execute this to get the list that you want:

```
List<Student> = em.createQuery("select s from School s", Student.class).getResultList();
```